# Change Unity3D prefab image during runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I have an inventory of objects in a game, with image and description.

To represent it, I want a scrollable list with a grid (made with a UI canvas with a scroll view inside), and every element of the grid is a prefab, composed by a UI Panel with an Image and a Text.

[image: Prefab appearance]

[image: Prefab hierarchy]

I've tried assigning the values of the Image and the Text programmatically in the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PopulateGrid : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab;
    public Sprite mySprite;

    private void Start()
    {
        Populate();
    }

    public void Populate()
    {
        GameObject newObj;

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
            newObj = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, transform); //prefab has image + text
            newObj.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "test" + i;
            newObj.GetComponentInChildren<Image>().sprite = mySprite; //I've also tried .overrideSprite
        }
    }
}
```

The funny thing is, **the Text gets correctly updated, while the Image doesn't**. I'm accessing them in the same way, but one acts like I want it to and the other one does his thing.

This is the end result:

[image: List with updated text but not updated images]

**UPDATE**: more details! Here's the code at runtime showing that the Image sprite does indeed get assigned

[image: Code at execution]

and here's my inspector:

[image: Inspector]

Comment: It looks like it's doing what it's supposed to. You are Instantiating a prefab, you are assigning a new text, but the value of mySprite doesn't appear to ever change. You've made it a property to be assigned in the Inspector but after that it never changes.

Comment: Mind your phrasing: `Prefab` refers to a template asset. Once this prefab was instantiated or when talking about objects in a scene in general it is no longer called "prefab" but simply a `GameObject`

Comment: It seems that your `mySprite` is simply `null` in the moment your code is executed ....

Comment: In the inspector, I assigned a sprite to the mySprite variable, and I'm assigning this to the Prefab Image. I thought it was supposed to work like this? Can I formulate it in another way so that it works?

Comment: Could you a) show us a screenshot of your settings and b) set a breakpoint and debug your code at `newObj.GetComponentInChildren<Image>().sprite = mySprite;` .. I bet `mySprite` will be `null` at this point otherwise you would get exceptions in the console pointing out what's wrong. Also note: `Panel` itself usually contains an `Image` component by default .... is it possible you are stting the sprite there ?

Comment: What do you mean my settings? you mean Edit > Preferences? I'm taking the screenshot of the breakpoint at the code right away.

Comment: @derHugo I can confirm that the sprite gets assigned and that it's not null: https://i.imgur.com/RHhBHpZ.png however it isn't registered as such during code execution

Comment: I mean a screenshot of the Inspector of your component. Anyway as said: Does your `Panel` object itself have an `Image` component? If this is the case you are setting the sprite in the wrong spot

Comment: @derHugo the Panel object does have an Image component, and its sprite getting recognized and assigned during runtime (as per the previous screenshot I posted). Here's my Inspector: https://i.imgur.com/DYYgHwu.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say that the `Panel` object itself also has an `Image` component you do not want to use [`GetComponentInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html) since it also returns any `Image` attached to the `newObj` itself!

Your code doesn't throw an exception but assigns the `mySprite` to the `Image` component of the `Panel` object, not its children called `Image`.

---

You would either have to use e.g.

```
newObj.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>()
```

or as mentioned create your own class and attach it to the prefab like e.g.

```
public class TileController : Monobehaviour 
{   
    // Reference these via the Inspector in the prefab
    [SerializeField] private Text _text;
    [SerializeField] private Image _image;

    public void Initialize(Sprite sprite, String text)
    {
        _image.sprite = sprite;
        _text.text = text;
    }
}
```

and then do

```
// using the correct type here makes sure you can only reference a GameObject
// that actually HAS the required component attached
[SerializeField] private TileController _prefab;

public void Populate()
{
    TileController newObj;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        // no cast needed since Instantiate returns the type of the prefab anyway
        newObj = Instantiate(_prefab, transform);
        newObj.Initialize(mySprite, "test" + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: you wizard! It works! I'm still getting used to Unity and I didn't realize my mistake. I'm so grateful, thanks! I'll use your and cesartalves suggestion of creating a specific Prefab class in the future to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure GetComponentInChildren is pointing to the right Image component? I would create a custom MonoBehaviour class for your prefab, and create a SetImage() method that points to the correct Image. When using GetComponentInChildren, it will return the first component found, and this can lead to unexpected behaviour.

You can do a Debug on `newObj.GetComponentInChildren<Image>()` to verify that it's the right component. Your code seems to be OK.

Comment: There's only one image in the Panel, I thought it would get that one to be modified, right? Or is it possible that it's not finding it somehow? I'm confused because the Text has been found, but I don't know if under the hood they behave differently. Anyhow I'll try to create a Monobehaviour class for the prefab and I'll see how it goes, thanks!

Comment: I checked your code against an old one of mine and you're assigning the sprite correctly. So doing a Debug.Log on the image component could be used to check it's the right one. From my experience there's always a chance there's some hidden Image component being picked up. Just try and see if it works ^^;

Comment: I've checked during execution and the sprite *does* get assigned! i.imgur.com/RHhBHpZ.png this is weird because it seems like it "forgets" its assignment somehow